# How can I remove TextField focus when tapping a different view using .focused()?

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios15

I'm trying to use iOS15's .focused() modifier to enable the user to tap anywhere outside of a text field to remove focus. I am going off of the example provided in: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GqXVFXnLVH4. Below is my non-working attempt:

```
enum Field {
  case textField
  case notTextField
}

struct ContentView: View {

  @State var textInput = ""
  @FocusState var focusState:Field?

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      TextField("Enter some text...", text: $textInput)
        .focused($focusState, equals: .textField)
      Rectangle()
        .focused($focusState, equals: .notTextField)
        .onTapGesture {
          state = .notTextField
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution was not to focus another element, but to switch the textfield's focus to false:

```
@State var textInput = ""
@FocusState var textFieldIsFocused: Bool

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TextField("Enter some text...", text: $textInput)
            .focused($textFieldIsFocused)
        Rectangle()
            .onTapGesture {
                textFieldIsFocused = false
            }
    }
}
```